# Dictionary of standardized engineering terms?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I think I once used a dictionary of engineering terms that was either a European effort or one of an (global) international standardization body - but I can't remember...

Answer (score 1):

I saw "European EN, DIN, ISO, IEC and VDA Standards" somewhere and then found it using https://duckduckgo.com/?q=iec+dictionary

- http://www.electropedia.org/